# Setting Up Devise with Recaptcha - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, recaptcha

I have tried setting this up based on previously asked questionshere on stack overflow but haven't been able to get it working. The captcha is showing up on my forms but a user can still register without filling in the recaptcha.

I'm working with the following instructions.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

1. I've got my private and public recaptcha keys

Environment.rb

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']  = 'mykey1234567'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = 'mykey1234567'
```

1. I've installed the recaptcha gem.

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise', '1.1.7'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

1. I've added recaptcha tags to my registration view.

new.html.erb

```
      <%= recaptcha_tags %>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
```

1. Created Registrations Controller

   rails generate controller Registrations create

Registrations Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
      if verify_recaptcha
        super
      else
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
        render_with_scope :new
      end
    end
end
```

I am supposed to edit my routes file but not sure what exactly which may be the cause of the issue.

My Routes File

```
  devise_for :troopers, :path => "troopers", :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to tell Devise to use your customized RegistrationsController. You do this by specifying the `:controllers` options in your `devise_for` declaration. Without this the `Devise::RegistrationsController` is called, which probably explains why recaptcha isn't working.

```
  devise_for :troopers,
             :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" },
             :path => "troopers",
             :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

Comment: I've changed my routes file to the following.

`devise_for :troopers, 
:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, 
:path => "troopers", 
:path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }`

This seems to work but I don't get any error messages now. Is this an issue with the view?

Comment: You need pass the model object when calling `verify_recaptcha` in your controller, e.g. `verify_recaptcha(:model => resource)`. There are additional options you can also specify such as a customized error message. Check out the [recaptcha/rails documentation](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha).

Comment: I will look doc links. I've changed the create method in custom registrations controller from flash[:alert] to flash[:notice] which seems to work ok. Thanks for your help.